# Querying the viewport values

Tags: javascript, firefox, browser

How can you get the Firefox browser viewPort values like `innerHeight`, `mozinnerScreenx` from the webpage using Javascript?

Comment: @ubercooluk: Sometimes I seriously wish I could downvote comments... Right, jQuery is going to fix typos and wrong capitalization, for sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
console.log(window.innerHeight);
console.log(window.mozInnerScreenX);
// etc.
```

Comment: i got it .its window.top.innerHeight and window.top.mozInnerScreenY